# How to activate a button in vba where the on click event is the only identifier?

Tags: events, vba, onclick, html-parsing

Hi I've tried different methods but with no succes. Can anyone figure out how to activate the event on this button:

```
<b>Class="palette" Title="Tilf&oslash;j" 
  onclick ="paletteAdd('databank_form_frekvens_dualListBox_choices', 
                       'databank_form_frekvens_dualListBox_selection',
                       'databank_form_frekvens_dualListBox_recorder');" 
  img src=   
  "/jobindsats/viewer/resources/com.sas.jobindsats.ui.palette.Palette/add.gif" 
  alt = "Tilf&oslash;j".</b>
```

The code so far clicks two buttons on the first page and activates/selects all the variables on the second page. But i cant seem to click on the individuel arrow buttons sending the selected values from the left box to the right box. The problem is that they all have the same names, titles,etc. only difference is the onclick event...

Code:

```
Sub makro()
Dim IE As Object
Dim frm As Object
Dim elc As HTMLHtmlElement

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://www.jobindsats.dk/sw167.asp"
    Do Until .readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    End With

    frm.document.getElementByID("form_gruppe_maalingsgrupper_0_maalinger_1_radio").Click
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

    frm.document.getElementByID("nextbutton").Click
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)

      'Ledighedstype
     frm.document.all("databank_form_forcedDimensions_0_placeholder_dual_choices").Options(1).Selected = True
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
        'doesnt work
   Set elc = frm.document.all.Title("Tilf&oslash;j")
   For Each elc In frm.document.all
   If elc.onclick = "form_gruppe_maalingsgrupper_0_maalinger_1_radio" Then
    elc.Click
   End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: The code so far doesn't work for me to do what you indicated. You never assign anything to frm so it fails as soon as you get to frm.document etc...